# How to get external IP addresses of 2 ISPs on Mac OSX

Tags: ip-address, osx-mavericks

The next code displays the external ip of 1 ISP.

curl ipecho.net/plain; echo

Is there any code to display the external ip of 2 ISPs?

My mac mini is connected to 2 internet providers.
One in en0 via ethernet and the other one in en3 via USB ethernet.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` has an `--interface` option which does exactly what you need.

Comment: I write: curl --interface eth0 ipecho.net/plain; echo

Comment: but nothing happens

Comment: What is "nothing"? How are the interfaces called on Mac?

Comment: sorry Jasper. My knowledge in terminal commands are pretty poor. I try to figure it out by myself but cannot do it. I beg you pardon if I cannot be more specific. I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: What is the output of the `ifconfig` command? What are `en0` and `en3` in your question?

Comment: en0 and en3 are the "BSD Device Name" of the interfaces that show in my OSX network information.

Comment: then try curl --interface en3 ipecho.net/plain